# Wrapping Dropbox with Mercurial for version control - crazy idea?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, dropbox

I currently use Dropbox as my "backup" solution for source and resources - and it's fine and dandy and has saved my bacon many times.

I find myself in need of a proper version control system now tho - and I really don't want to put a repository INSIDE my Dropbox folder.

For one thing, it will fill my Dropbox allowance pretty quickly - for another, I don't really want Dropbox and the version-control software 'fighting' over files.

So I'm thinking of doing something like this (I'm using Mercurial but I'm sure the same theory applies to other VC stuff)

```
MYDOCS Folder <-- this is where the repo will go
    .hg (for Mercurial in this case)
    DROPBOX Folder
        WORK FOLDER
            PROJECT1
            PROJECT2
            PROJECT3
            ...
```

That way, everything I work on is covered by Dropbox - but my version control is outside of Dropbox.

Obviously not every file in my DROPBOX folder is version controlled - and I'm stuck with only 1 Repository for ALL my work (not ideal) but can anyone see any other snags with this approach?

Note: MYDOCS is backed-up separately (much less often) so there's no risk of file loss here.

p.s.

I spent a bit of time over the weekend implementing this (using Mercurial/TortoiseHG) and it seems to work quite well.

There are some snags - you have to set aggressive ignore filters (in the end I just used "*" and added code manually) otherwise TortoiseHG has a heart-attack staring at 10s of 1000s of files every time it looks for changes/new files to add.

This means it won't spot new files in existing projects too which is a minor pain-in-the-neck - it would be great if Mercurial actually had an INCLUDE filter at times like this...

p.p.s. I had a bright idea to make this a BIT easier.

I created a new folder outside the Dropbox called "Repo" and inside that I created a Directory Junction (link for you *nix types) to the directory inside my Dropbox which contains all my source (my Eclipse Workspace directory - basically).

I then put my repo into the 'repo' folder - that way it's not overseeing my entire Dropbox, just the part of it I want it to - and it's still not 'inside' my Dropbox ;)

Comment: Definitely never put the Mercurial repo in a Dropbox. Not only because of the size, but Mercurial operates on certain basic constraints such as that the repository directory doesn’t just change underneath it or that files don’t get locked out of the blue, and these are not at all valid with Dropbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you point out, the major drawback of this approach is that you're tied to a single repository. One of the big advantages of distributed version control systems like Mercurial is that repositories are cheap to create and use for isolated little projects.

Why not just use [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) for your version control needs? You can create as many private repositories as you want and use as much disk as you want. The only drawback here is that you're limited to how many users you can share them with, but given the approach you outlined above, that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: I already use BitBucket - what I don't want to have to do is create a new repo for EVERY project (which, as I work with Eclipse, is pretty much my only alternative).

Any other solution - creating separate repos or subrepos - will put .hg  into the DROPBOX folder which I definately don't want to do!

Comment: A repo for every project - seems normal, what’s the problem with that? Why would you want to have projects without version control?

Comment: Because an Eclipse Project in no way represents a single Application/Deliverable/Piece-of-work.  I have DOZENS of library projects - I need separate projects for a free and paid-for version of the same (with bits disabled in the case of the free version) code etc. etc.

Comment: Same thing, a repo for every library, a repo (branch) for each deliverable - seems normal :).

Comment: A repo should contain a logical 'set' of software - think of it from the point-of-view of someone accessing the repo to clone it, can they get everything they need from that repo??  If you put every project into a different repo, the answer is no and you've made a load of work for someone (and yourself)!?

Comment: I think this answer pretty much encapsulates where I went with this, so I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't suffer the repository corruption one sees when keeping the .hg directory in Dropbox, but you'll probably end up committing less which is a bummer too.

Comment: In this case I'm really using version control as a way of easily seeing changes/accessing a version of my work at a particular point-in-time (a release, basically).  I work solo atm so I don't need to commit work for others to use...

Comment: I commit work for me to use.  A permanent, indelible history is an asset even in solo work.  There's a reason scientists keep their log books (and in pen).

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial hard-codes the root to be on the same level as the working directory, so I don’t think you can change this.

What you could do however is to symlink the `.hg` directory to another directory:

```
cd WORK_FOLDER
ln -s ../MYDOCS_Folder/.hg .hg
hg up null   # to reset the dirstate
hg up
```

Mercurial will follow the symbolic link and operate as normal, but probably Dropbox (if it’s behaving sanely) won’t. When you do this, make sure to never do any operations in `WORK FOLDER` because that will mess things up.

To be honest I wouldn’t recommend this kind of workflow though, it seems fragile.

Comment: The idea of using a symlink to move an .hg folder seems scary for sure!!

Comment: The whole concept of operating Mercurial on a Dropbox and trying to pull it apart in such a manner is kinda scary if you ask me. :) But given what you are trying to do, I think this answer describes the only approach that will work. A symlink to `.hg` shoudn’t be a problem for Mercurial.